# Display query results like \G in MySQL when using Oracle / sqlplus?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

In MySQL, you can use \G to run a query:

```
select * from mytable\G
```

And your results will be displayed in an inverted table, kinda like this:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                 column1: 12345
           another_colum: another value
             yet_another: ABCD
*************************** 2. row ***************************
                 column1: 238479
           another_colum: another value again
             yet_another: WXYZ
```

Is there any way to get a similar format using Oracle / sqlplus?

Answer (score 4):

There is a utility Tom Kyte has created called [print_table](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1035431863958) that does roughly the same thing.